# Why I'm getting this error working with table view data management?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm building an app that is a sort of a to-do list for school. I've created a class called DataService which manage data for me, here's the code to it:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DataService {
   static let instance = DataService()

   let KEY_ATIVS = "atividades"
   let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

   private var _loadedAtivs = [Atividade]()

   var loadedAtivs: [Atividade] {
       return _loadedAtivs
   }

   func saveAtivs() {
        let ativsData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(_loadedAtivs)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(ativsData, forKey: KEY_ATIVS)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

   func loadAtivs() {
        if let ativsData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(KEY_ATIVS) as? NSData {
        if let atividades = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(ativsData) as? [Atividade] {
            _loadedAtivs = atividades
        } 
    }

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(NSNotification(name: "atividadesLoaded", object: nil))
}

    func addAtiv(ativ: Atividade) {
        _loadedAtivs.append(ativ)
         saveAtivs()
         loadAtivs()
     }

func scheduleNotification(text: String, fireDate: NSDate) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = fireDate
    notification.alertTitle = "Lembrete de atividade"
    notification.alertBody = text
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    app.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}

func removeAtiv(index: NSIndexPath) {
    _loadedAtivs.removeAtIndex(index.row)
    app.cancelLocalNotification(app.scheduledLocalNotifications![index.row])
       saveAtivs()
   }
```

}

**NOTE:** *Atividade* IS A CUSTOM CLASS

I'm using a table view to display the array in cells, for that, I've created a custom table view cell class which has a function called "configureCell" that uses the array[indexPath.row] to configure each cell individually. Check the code where I do it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AtivCell") as? AtivCell {

   cell.configureCell(DataService.instance.loadedAtivs[indexPath.row])                  
        return cell
    } else {
        return AtivCell()
    }
 }
```

The table view is working fine, the problem is while trying to delete an element out of the array. I'm using this code to do so:

```
    DataService.instance.removeAtiv(indexPath)
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
     DataService.instance.loadAtivs()
```

But it's crashing and giving me the following error:

```
2016-04-17 22:18:39.549 Homework[2430:249856] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3505.17/UITableView.m:1718
2016-04-17 22:18:39.550 Homework[2430:249856] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182154f5c 0x196d4bf80 0x182154e2c 0x183043f3c 0x18789d028     0x1878b77bc 0x10013f0dc 0x100106328 0x100106140 0x100106190 0x187afb180 0x187afb918 0x1879f3bf4 0x1879f6ddc 0x1877d7088 0x1876e580c 0x1876e5308 0x1876e5190 0x186eb5040 0x1009edd30 0x1009f3780 0x18210c258 0x18210a0c0 0x182038dc0 0x18d18c088 0x187712f44 0x10015d9f8 0x1975768b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I have no idea of why the error is happening. I'm deleting the element out of the array, saving the array without the element, deleting the row in the table view and loading the array again to the configureCell function, so why is the crash happening and how would I fix it?

**PLEASE HELP ME!**

**NOTE:** THE ELEMENT IS BEING DELETED FROM THE ARRAY AFTER THE CRASH, BUT OF COURSE I DON'T WANT THE USER TO EXPERIENCE A CRASH JUST TO DELETE SOME ELEMENT OF AN ARRAY

Comment: What does your `numberOfRowsInSection` method look like?  In general you want make sure that the table view knows that your data source has one less element before you delete it.

Comment: THAT WAS THE PROBLEM!!!! Oh my god. The problem is that I was storing the DataService.instance.loadedAtivs in a constant called ativs, and in the numberOfRowsInSection I was returning this count. When I now changed to return not the constant but the value itself, it worked, thanks a lot!!!!!!